# Login and Logout functionality using Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am building a project using Java Spring Framework and MongoDB. I am trying to create login and logout functionality, by taking the data using @RequestParam in the Controller and then checking it with the details saved in database.
I want to build a logout functionality so that no one can reopen the previous pages and functions, the session should be active till the user is logged in. Otherwise, it will again ask for the login. 
Can anyone provide me a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That solution is called Spring Security... Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I am pretty much confused in using Spring Security.

Comment: Then ask a question about that instead of trying to create your own secure security framework. Generally it is just a matter of configuring it...

Comment: It is good to use a simple token based approach in mongoDB using memcache, Instead of spring security. Which is stateful.

Comment: Swings and roundabouts, I've written my own security implementation before.  It was simpler than spring security, but obviously spring security is a whole lot more powerful and flexible.

Comment: How to do it without using Spring Security?

Comment: Well, my solution was to simply have an authentication method which checks user credentials against the database, then add properties to the user session like isLoggedIn, or hasRole.  Then whenever you need to protect a resource, in your controller method you just check the session for those properties.

Comment: But for a real enterprise application, dont skimp on security, go with a real framework.

Comment: http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-security-custom-login-page.jsp
I tried using this approach, but my username and password are saved in database. How do I implement this.?